# Setting Vim's NoSpell for command

Tags: glossaries, vim

I'm trying to switch off Vim's spell-checking for the glossaries command `\gls`. I really don't understand how the syntax matching works but I'm trying the following in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim`:

```
syn region texGlsZone matchgroup=texStatement start="\\gls\(pl)\s*{" end="}\|%stopzone\>" contains=@NoSpell
```

This doesn't work and I can't see how to debug. The Hilinks plugin (when I can get it to work) tells me the `gls` text has this syntax stack:

```
SynStack:  texChapterZone->texSectionZone->texSubSectionZone->texStatement  HltTrace: texStatement->Statement
```

and the text inside the curly braces have:

```
SynStack:  texChapterZone->texSectionZone->texSubSectionZone  HltTrace: texSubSectionZone
```

Has anyone done this or something like it themselves?

Comment: Stupid mistake, syntax highlighting happens after filetype detection so my changes were overridden. I'll answer this properly when stackexchange allows me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, stupid question. Syntax highlighting was happening after my filetype changes. So instead of adding rules to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim` add them to `~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim` so they override the defaults instead of the reverse.

Oh well, maybe that'll help someone else.